# Bluetooth connection log

Tags: bluetooth, connection, event-log

Is there a way to obtain the Bluetooth connection history from windows 10? I want to find out how long a device remained connected?

I checked the details tab under device manager. But it only shows the last connected time, not the duration of time connected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Admin Tools, Event Viewer and build a filter to see Bluetooth. I am curious to understand why you might need this?  Bluetooth is just a short distance Wireless and something that is very commonly used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to troubleshoot some issues with my BT speaker. Can you tell me which section under the event viewer I should look? I am not able to find it using simple search

Comment: Start here (lots to look at / for) Event View, Windows Log, System and when System is open, Action, Find and search for Bluetooth. This will produce results. There may be other sections as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Computer Management / Event Viewer, look for Applications and Service Logs, Microsoft, Windows, Bluetooth-Policy, Operational. Enable this log. When a bluetooth device is connected, an event should show up. I have Source as Bluetooth-Policy and Event ID is 9.

For some reason, a disconnection event is not recorded here. I'm using a bluetooth keypad, and it's recognized by Windows as a Bluetooth HID device. Not sure if that's your case, but could be similar.

To look for disconnection events, go to Windows Logs, System, find warning messages from Source HidBth, Event ID is 2 in my case.

Comment: I found it. Thanks, Yvon.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found was:

1. Using app: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html
2. in settings, choose to show logs only X minutes (to avoid slow refresh)
3. trigger desired action
4. refresh the app to see the events

---

without app, you might try this: **`Device Manager -> Your device -> Properties -> Events -> View All Events`** (however, I didn't have a luck)